# python dictionary mysql not insert

Tags: python, mysql

I obtaines a dictionary 'p' from the following code,but cannot able to insert into the mysql database.please help me to insert the datas into database.

dictionary is :[('Casssandraw', 'Cooking'), ('Archanea', 'Playing'), ('Adarshan', 'Programming'), ('Leelal', 'Baking')]
should be stored to Names and Hobby fields.

```
Name       Hobby
Cassandraw Cooking
Archanea   Playing
...        ...
```

Program:

```
import MySQLdb
import re
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # n

with open('qwer2.txt','r') as file, db as cursor:
    f = open('qwer2.txt', 'r')

    lines = f.readlines()

    for x in lines:
       p=re.findall(r'(?:name is|me)\s+(\w+).*?(?:interest|hobby)\s+is\s+(\w+)',x, re.I)
       print p

       cursor.execute(
       '''INSERT INTO Details (Names, Hobby)
          VALUES (%s, %s)''',
         (name, hobby))#<-donot know what to provide
db.commit()
```

Comment: Are you getting some errors?

Comment: yes i get errors as name not defined,but donot know what to provide instead of name and hobby!

Comment: where are you getting names and hobbies from, your regex? Also where is your dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a list of tuples containing name/hobby not a dict:

You can unpack the two and insert:

```
for name, hobby in p: # I am presuming p is the list you posted in your question
     cursor.execute(
       '''INSERT INTO Details (Names, Hobby)
          VALUES (%s, %s)''',
         (name, hobby))#<-donot know what to provide


for name,hobby in p: 
     print name,hobby
Casssandraw Cooking
Archanea Playing
Adarshan Programming
Leelal Baking
```

Comment: wow,this is what i was searching for a entire yesterday!thank you so much,now it works!